# How do i build percentage glyphicon star icon to fill decimal average rating?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, woff

I will be given average rating like 4.3 and i need to build the logic to display 4.3 average rating in the star icon(4 whole stars,5th star as partial filled). Max rating number is 5. I have created jsfiddle by referring the stackoverflow examples and i am not getting partial star in my draft fiddle and i am getting the whole star as result.[My JSFiddle Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nklb.png)

**JSFiddle Link** : https://goo.gl/sz1YIJ  Kindly advice.

Comment: There are tons of examples and scripts all over the web for ratings stars. This question is too broad for this site

Comment: @ChrisW. forgot that was there... nope!! lol

Comment: @charlietfl sorry but that cracked me right up! Had to ask. cheers!

Comment: You want it to clip off the right half of the 5th star for 4.5?

Comment: @charlietfl  In the below JSFiddle example, though i gave decimal rating, still it shows for the whole star. I am not getting the artial star https://jsfiddle.net/user435243/gajmh2v5/6/

Comment: @doug65536 Yes. I am looking my 5th star as 4.5 filled. Here is my jsfiddle where i am trying to make partial star https://jsfiddle.net/user435243/gajmh2v5/6/

Comment: @ChrisW. I have updated my question and find below my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/user435243/gajmh2v5/6/

Comment: If it were me, and you need get actually pretty exact. I'd just make and SVG with the star shapes cut-out and the Fill of the rest of it whatever color the background would be and slap a progressbar or something behind it to just give the illusion of stars getting filled while providing you an easy medium to throw your specific rating amount in there and call it done. It is a pretty broad question though.

Comment: Check out: http://github.com/arbelh/HalfStyle a novel approach to .5 and .33 which may be a stepping stone to your solultion, but in my implementations I do either a png or svg exactly as @ChrisW. mentioned. You can animate both as well, which gives a nice effect.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:**

In response to comments, there are hundreds of useful unicode symbols that you can copy and paste into your code, e.g., ▲ ▼ ★ . These work better than icon images because you can set the color and size with css. To find a symbol, like the man in the title below, try searching [unicode-table](http://unicode-table.com/en/)

## A simple solution

---

Seems this could be done very simply with just a tiny bit of css and Javascript.

Here we have a div with 5 stars. We adjust the width to show or hide the stars. The key is to use overflow hidden and inline-block styles and then capture the clientWidth on initialization. This was more reliable than using em units or other methods.

Obviously you could enhance it more, but I wanted to show the minimum code required.

**Run the snippet and enter any fractional star value from 0 to 5.**

```js
var cw = window.rating1.clientWidth; // save original 100% pixel width

function rating( stars ) {
  window.rating1.style.width = Math.round(cw * (stars / 5)) + 'px';
}

rating(4.3);
```

```css
.rating {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rating::before { 
  content: "★★★★★" 
}
```

```html
Enter a star rating 0-5: <input onkeyup="rating(this.value)" value="4.3"> 
<p>
<div id="rating1" class="rating"></div>
```

Comment: Looks simple and great. How did you add the star symbol in the code?

Comment: He used ascii, like another cool option would be `&#10029;` `\272D`, this is slick man I dig it! Didn't even consider ascii icons! +1

Comment: @user5970552 - Thanks. I've added a link to my answer where you can find more of these symbols.

Comment: @doug65536 - Thanks. One can easily set the font family in the css when needed. It's also very easy to load additional fonts for special symbols, e.g., [Font-Awesome Icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts), [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/), etc. Yet, common symbols like arrows and stars are almost always available from the pre-loaded system fonts.

Comment: Excellent! Short and Sweet answer to the much needed functionality

Answer (score 3):

I have written a function that does what you needed. It simply sets the width of the partial icon, with overflow hidden.

```js
function setFractionalRating(container, value) {
    var floor = Math.floor(value),
        ceil = Math.ceil(value),
        star = container.children[floor],
        slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        children = slice.call(container.children),
        visible = slice.call(children, 0, ceil),
        hidden = slice.call(children, ceil),
        size,
        width,
        portion;
  
    visible.forEach(function(star) {
        star.style.visibility = 'visible';
       star.style.width = '';
    });
    hidden.forEach(function(star) {
        star.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        star.style.width = '';
    });

    size = star && star.getBoundingClientRect();
    width = size && size.width;
    portion = value - floor;

    if (star && portion !== 0)
        star.style.width = (width * portion) + 'px';
}


// Test:
var check = 1,
    debug = document.querySelector('.debug');
debug.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
setInterval(function(rating) {
    debug.firstChild.nodeValue = check.toFixed(1);
    setFractionalRating(rating, check);
    if ((check += 0.1) >= 5)
        check = 0.1;
}, 200, document.querySelector('.rating'));
```

```css
.rating > i {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rating">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
</div>
<div class="debug">
</div>
</div>
```